# How to save Lenovo Ideapad Flexbook with a 1234F command prompt and boot issues

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, mbr

I got a little bit overzealous when trying to make my Windows 8.1 Ideapad dual boot Linux and now I'm afraid I'm about to lose 2 whole OS's worth of mission-critical data. Here's what happened:

I have Windows 8.1 installed and I resized the 500GB HDD to 400GB so that I had a 100GB partition for Linux. I then thought that I could use EasyBCD to simultaneously install NeoGRUB  with Debian linux and use the Windows boot loader to select what OS I want. I was successful in editing the boot load menu to make it include "Debian Linux" as an option, as well as the Lenovo System Recovery partition, but only the Windows 8.1 OS would boot without error (only the menu was edited; Linux never installed).

So next I used UNetbootin to make a Debian USB and installed Debian to the empty partition. This seemed to work fine and I used Debian for about 12 hours, probably rebooting fine at least once or twice.

However, then I got really dumb and tried to restore the Windows boot loader because I liked it better and Windows is my main OS on this computer. I followed a tut that said to use [testdisk] (http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk) . I tried to restore the MBR but now all I get is the

```
1234F
```

prompt. It doesn't do anything except return the

```
1234F
```

prompt regardless of if I press 1, 2, 3, 4, F, or Enter (or anything else). I can reboot with Ctl-Alt-Del but that's it and it won't boot from USB that I can tell. I tried using UNetbootin to make a System Rescue CD on USB but it didn't boot.

When it starts it flashes the "Lenovo" screen with only the Lenovo logo/name for just half a second but no matter what I press/hold it won't boot off anything or go to the BIOS.

Comment: I'm guessing you've got a GPT disk and wrote an MBR to it, which has your system very confused.  Hold the power button, making sure to power off (as opposed to a low-power/sleep state, which is what most of these modern systems do), and then boot, which should let you access the BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: You're right about the problem I think, but it just will not boot off anything and I've shut it totally off then back on dozens of times :(

Comment: I assume you've tried Fn+F2 while booting?  As stated previously, you'll want to power off the system, as opposed to just using Ctrl-Alt-Del . . .

Comment: Now I can access my BIOS! Thanks, I didn't know Fn+F2, I just tried all the keys not key combos.

Comment: What now tho? It won't boot from USB even though USB boot is enabled...

Comment: What are you trying to boot off of?  If you're system isn't in Legacy/CSM mode, you're going to have to have UEFI bootable media . . .

Comment: It's just a normal flashdrive. Is there a way to make it UEFI bootable?

Comment: I usually recommend Rufus - just make sure to pick GPT format . . .

Comment: Rufus is only for Windows and UNetbootin doesn't say anything about UEFI. I started following a long command line tut by Ubuntu (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/USBStickUEFIHowto) but I got blocked with errors. I'm trying to run Fedora's liveusb-creator python script now, but it also gives errors...

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that EFI/UEFI isn't simply a new BIOS feature; it's a *replacement for* the 30-year-old BIOS. EFI also uses a new partition table type (GPT) that's replacing the older MBR. Thus, the huge chest full of BIOS- and MBR-centric tools for managing dual-boot configurations is pretty much useless on EFI-based computers. You should *forget* everything you ever knew about dual-booting when you deal with EFI. Also, if you run across a product and it doesn't explicitly state the boot method (BIOS vs. EFI) or partition table type (MBR vs. GPT), you should assume it's for the older BIOS and MBR systems.

That done, you can begin learning about EFI and GPT. Unfortunately, there's a lot of bad information on the Internet on this topic. Three sources you might try include:

- [My page on Linux EFI-mode installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [Adam Williamson's page on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on using EFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

That last is more Ubuntu-centric than the others, but you might still glean something useful from it even if you're not using Ubuntu.

As to your problem specifically, if your partition table has been damaged, you may be able to recover it with the help of my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) utility. See in particular the [GPT fdisk documentation on fixing GPT problems.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html)

It's not clear that your partition table is damaged, though; it could be that your boot loader is damaged or missing. In that case, fixing the Windows boot loader will require running a Windows recovery tool, and you can then [install any Linux EFI boot loader you like.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/)

More specific advice will require more specific information from you. You could run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from a live CD, post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates to a pastebin site, and post the URL to your document here. That will give us a better idea of what's happening on your system.

Comment: Thank you so much Rod. I'm trying this now and will update the thread ASAP... hmm just got an 'Error wrong architecture: amd64' message on Sourceforge trying to download GPT fdisk...

Comment: OK, so, the only other computer I have to help me fix the broken one runs 32bit Ubuntu. gdisk was a .deb and I guess I'm supposed to install it on the Ubuntu computer but its got the wrong architecture and like you alluded to, I think the problem is with the boot loader. With no Windows disk/comp to make a recovery tool, I'm trying the Boot Info Script tool you mentioned.

Comment: Update: No luck. I tried GPT and Boot Info Script as well as Super Grub Disk but the computer just will not boot off USB. There's not an optical drive but I guess I will try making a CD and borrowing an external optical drive because that's the only thing I can think of. I've never seen a laptop this bricked before...